# Search in Excel

Tags: python

I have a python code here that reads the phone numbers from the Excel using a list of ICCID and also writes them back into an Excel. Unfortunately, the numbers where he does not find are ignored. But I would like him to write this as "not found" in the Excel list as well.

Source to search is a txt File:

```
 89410211684401105500
 89410211684402105500
 89410211684403105500
 89410211684404105500
 89410211684405105500
```

search file is alle_08.12.2022.xlsx, it has 2 columns (ICCID Nummer)

```
89410211684401105500    0763029300
89410211684402105500    0763029400
89410211684403105500    0763029500
89410211684404105500    0763029600
```

output in output.xlsx should look like this in 2 columns

```
0763029300 89410211684401105500 
0763029400 89410211684402105500 
0763029500 89410211684403105500 
0763029600 89410211684404105500
not found  89410211684405105500
```

code:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter


def main():
    path = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\'
    alle_nummern = path + 'alle_08.12.2022.xlsx'

    wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path + 'output.xlsx')
    ws = wb.add_worksheet('Tabelle1')
    ws.set_column(0, 2, 22)
    format = wb.add_format({'num_format': '@'})

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    row = 1

    with open(file_path) as fp:
        Lines = fp.readlines()

        for line in Lines:
            lline = line.strip()
            df = pd.read_excel(alle_nummern, dtype=str)
            df_abc = df[df["ICCID"] == lline]

            for rows in df_abc.itertuples():
                print('Nummer', rows[2], 'ICCID', rows[1])
                ws.write_row(0, 0, ['Telefonnummer', 'ICCID'], format)
                ws.write_row(row, 0, [rows[2], rows[1]], format)
                row = row + 1

    wb.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you provide an example of your data? is all row missing or only one column when it doesn't find values?

Comment: and which is your actual output? I've tried your code and if i'm not missunderstandig it...it  creates a dataframe with 4 records, no with 5 as your source. Is possible to read your txt as a dataframe? or is mandatory use readlines()?

Comment: it doesn't matter how the data is read. I simply need all 5 data sets in the output file again. in this example 4 times with the number and once with "not found". It is important that all data sets are reflected in the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it, I have changed your logic and I have supposed that your source file ever has all records you need.
I have used a text file as source:

[image]

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import  filedialog
def main():

   path = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\' 

   alle_nummern = path + 'alle_08.12.2022.xlsx'
   root =Tk()
   root.withdraw()
   file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()


   lines = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None,dtype=str)
   lines.columns=['IC']


   df = pd.read_excel(alle_nummern,dtype=str)
   write = pd.merge(left=lines, right=df , left_on='IC' , right_on='ICCID', 
   how='left')
   write =write.drop(['ICCID'], axis=1)
   write['TELEFONENUMBER'].fillna('Not Found', inplace=True)


   with pd.ExcelWriter(path + 'output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', 
        if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
            write.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=f'Tabelle1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

output:

[image]

you can rename the column IC and change the type of columns.

I hope this approach helps you.

Comment: thank you very much, i have 2 errors. Unresolved reference 'Tk':8. I was able to fix the second error myself with "from tkinter import filedialog"

Comment: Oh sorry maybe this error is because I have changed `root = tk.Tk()` to `root=Tk()`. I have edit my answer to add some imports

Comment: great now it works. One more thing. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\output.xlsx', could you still fix this? If the file does not exist, the error occurs

Comment: Do you need modify existing file ? or it doesn't matter ? If you only want to write the file every once you execute your program you can change     `with pd.ExcelWriter(path + 'output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
                write.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=f'Tabelle1')` to      `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path+'\\output'+datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    write.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Tabelle1', index=False)
    writer.close()`    Or use os to check if file exist, else create

Comment: time mark is to differenciate files.  Another way is  use askopenfile to select in which file you want to write your data. But it changes a little the code

Comment: it's not a problem. we are leaving it like this. Thank you for your help